how to detect multiple keypresses in ncurses
I'm trying to make a crossplatform way to detect when multiple keys are held down in ncurses. I used https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/144558/key-released-multiple-keys-how-to-go-around-ncurses-limitations to write some code which is shown here
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int pressedKeys[200];



int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    addstr("test");
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    
    int r=0;
    while (true)
    {
        int c;
        while ((c = getch()) != ERR)
        {
            r=0;
            while (pressedKeys[r] != '\0')
            {
                pressedKeys[r]=c;
                r++;
            }
                
        }

        char m[200];
        m[0]=pressedKeys[0];
        m[1]=pressedKeys[1];
        int n=0;
        while (pressedKeys[n] != '\0')
        {
            n++;
        }
        clear();
        char s[1];
        sprintf(s,"%d",n);
        addstr("numkeys");
        addstr(s);

        addstr("keypresses");
        addstr(m);
        addstr("\n");

    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}


but it seems unable to detect any keypresses. it needs to just leave the pressedkeys string empty if there are no keys pressed down as well but currently well... it seems to always be empty, I was wondering if there was a way to fix it? it seems related to nodelay() but I need it as well...there needs to be no delay

Curses immediately reports all key presses, but it does not report key releases, as it cannot be done reliably across even modern terminal emulators. It is just not the way the terminal works. Therefore, detecting multiple keypresses comes down to watching the clock and hoping you get it right. BTW, the terminal is a terrible choice for writing a game. You’d be much better off playing with PyGame or something.

(Detecting actual keyboard state can be done when you are on GUI systems, but if you are using Win32 or X to detect keys, they why are you messing with the terminal?)


Curses immediately reports all...
thx
Detecting actual keyboard st
it would be funny to make something low level


The keyboard -is- a low-level device, though. I’m not saying you can’t make interactive games in the terminal — I’ve personally made more than a few — but it is a horrendous nightmare to get it right. And using a dedicated GUI game library is just so much easier.

Not all keyboards can even detect multiple presses of ANY two keys. It depends on hardware design of a keyboard.

The good news is that the vast majority of modern keyboards follow the same design (more or less) as variants of the IBM 105-key enhanced keyboard. But Curses was not designed to cater just to capable keyboards, but to all kinds of other, older keyboard hardware, many of which are pretty lacking.

As mentioned in this comment:

Curses immediately reports all key presses, but it does not report key releases, as it cannot be done reliably across even modern terminal emulators. It is just not the way the terminal works. Therefore, detecting multiple keypresses comes down to watching the clock and hoping you get it right. BTW, the terminal is a terrible choice for writing a game. You’d be much better off playing with PyGame or something
yeah it kinda just doesnt work I guess then, at least using pure C

